# How to find out if entity is used in relations somewhere in database?

Tags: mysql

I have an entity/table of employees. Somewhere in database (in many places actually) this entity can be used in relations/foreign keys.

The task is simple: if the employee is used somewhere, I shouldn't show "delete" button, otherwise employee can be deleted.

The question is not about how to achieve deleting (cascade/restrict foreign keys), it's more about how to return to client side information about "if the employee is used somewhere".

I use Laravel's ORM, and the thing is it feels quite clumsy to just to join / try to find employe in many places in DB manually (like, do many `joins` and `wheres` in order to try to find out if employee is used or not).

Is there any common solution for this? Even if I do it like I described it's going to be cumbersome. Or I should add a column like "is_taken" and handle the value programmatically on the server side?